# QGIS Add Script from file not working

Tags: qgis

I have a script in QGIS which will not add to the User Scripts when I choose Add script from file.

It does, however, drop into the 'scripts' folder. It still does not display though.

Any ideas?

Happens on both QGIS 2.18.17 and QGIS 3.0, but does not always happen on different machines.